# AngularJS $broadcast $on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcasting

I started to learn AngularJS recently. So, I try send a message from a controller to another. I saw a lot of examples and my code is similarly, but don't work.
Why $rootScope.$on don't work?
Someone can help me?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{message}}

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <p>Ctrl1</p>

        {{test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Ctrl:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("Ctrl",["$rootScope","$scope",Ctrl]);

function Ctrl($rootScope,$scope){

    var test = "Bla bla bla!";
    $scope.message = test;

    $rootScope.$broadcast('aaa', test); 
}
```

Ctrl1:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("Ctrl1",["$rootScope","$scope", Ctrl1]);

function Ctrl1($rootScope, $scope){

    $rootScope.$on('aaa', function(event, args){
        console.log("This message don't appear!");
        $scope.test=args;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work, because Parent controller `Ctrl` will get register before `Ctrl1` controller gets loaded. So while `$broadcast` event inner controller `Ctrl1` listner on event haven't been registered yet.

You could make it working by wrapping $broadcast of the event inside a $timeout function of parent controller. So it will wait get evaluated in next digest cycle.

```
$timeout(function(){
   $rootScope.$broadcast('aaa', test); 
})
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fd4cC5gtSvbaocc0WmOw?p=preview)